# How to enable per-app language preferences for Flutter android 13 app?

Tags: flutter, localization

I used this manual to enable per-app language preferences in my Flutter app:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages

Language selector appears in the settings, but how to connect it to the FLutter app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Flutter does not support this yet, there's [an open issue in the code repository about it](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109842), in case you want to look.

But, if you really need to add this feature, you can do it manually by adding the configurations in the `android` project. You can do this by [following instructions here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#use-localeconfig). In summarizing, you have to create a new XML file, add a `localeConfig` tag to your app manifest, and declare supported locales in `build.gradle` of your app.